# PowerShell Dictonary filtering out the failing ping

Tags: powershell, dictionary, output

I am trying to filter out the status=Offline Printers and sent that output to the $Body in the email, any ideas on how I can do this? So far the output shows all printers and IT's regardless of online or offline status.

```
    Clear-Host
$printerip = @( 
"192.168.141.104","192.168.141.250","192.168.141.251","192.168.141.53","192.168.141.157","192.168.141.167",
"192.168.141.115","192.168.141.116","192.168.142.25","192.168.142.23","192.168.1 44.80","192.168.144.57","192.168.150.51",
"192.168.150.50","192.168.150.40"
)

$printername = @(
"Shoreline Color", 
"Dockside B/W", 
"Shoreline B/W",
"Spinnaker",
"BA Ricoh Printer",
"BA Xerox Color",
"BA Lab 1",
"BA Lab 2",
"Dowagiac Ricoh",
"Dowagiac Xerox Color",
"Paw Paw Ricoh",
"Paw Paw Xerox Color",
"330 Finance 1",
"330 Finance 2",
"330 Copierr"
)

$status = @()
foreach($printer in $printerip){
if(Test-Connection $printer -Count 2 -Quiet){
$status += "Online"
}else{
$status += "Offline"
}}

$count   = $printerip.Count
$counter = 0
$report  = @()
do{
$report +=$status[$counter]+" - "+$printerip[$counter]+" -     "+$printername[$counter] 
$counter++
}until($counter -ge $count)

if($report -match 'offline'){$body = ("We should probably do something about     this! `n `n") + $report | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -From "PrinterTest@domain.org" -To  "name@domain.org" -Subject "Printer Test" -Body $body  -SmtpServer   "mail.domain.org"}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `do...until` loop, you would need an if statement to check whether `$status[$counter]` is equal to 'Offline' to only grab the offline printers, however, I would try something like this or try putting the printer information into its own separate csv file

```
$printers = @'
IP,Name,Status
192.168.141.104,Shoreline Color,
192.168.141.250,Dockside B/W,
192.168.141.251,Shoreline B/W,
192.168.141.53,Spinnaker,
192.168.141.157,BA Ricoh Printer,
192.168.141.167,BA Xerox Color,
192.168.141.115,BA Lab 1,
192.168.141.116,BA Lab 2,
192.168.142.25,Dowagiac Ricoh,
192.168.142.23,Dowagiac Xerox Color,
192.168.144.80,Paw Paw Ricoh,
192.168.144.57,Paw Paw Xerox Color,
192.168.150.51,330 Finance 1,
192.168.150.50,330 Finance 2,
192.168.150.40,330 Copierr,
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$printers | ForEach-Object {
    if (Test-Connection $_.ip -Count 2 -Quiet) {
        $_.status = 'Online'
    } else {
        $_.status = 'Offline'
    }
}

if ($printers.status -contains 'Offline') {
    $offlineprinters = $printers | Where-Object status -eq 'Offline' | Format-Table -AutoSize
    $body = "We should probably do something about this!`n`n" + $offlineprinters | Out-String
    Send-MailMessage -From 'email@domain.com' -To 'email@domain.com' -Subject 'Printer Test' -Body $body -SmtpServer 'smtp.domain.com'
}
```